# div not disappearing on scroll because of overflow:hidden / auto

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, fade

I've got this JavaScript

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $menu = $("header");
var opacity = $menu.css("opacity");
var scrollStopped;

var fadeInCallback = function () {
    if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(scrollStopped);
    }

    scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
        $menu.animate({ opacity: 1 }, "slow");
    }, 1400);
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
        $menu.animate({ opacity: 0 }, "200", fadeInCallback);
    } else {
        fadeInCallback.call(this);
    }
  });
});
```

It worked fine in hiding the header on scroll, but adding some height: 100%; to the html, body and a 'content div' with overflow hidden on html and body and auto on the 'content div' this javascript no longer works.

Any idea why this javascript doesn't work? And is there a fix or other way to do it so the header fades out when scrolling?

Thanks in advance

EDIT ----

A JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/AMJFG/

A newer Fiddle with less CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/AMJFG/1/

Comment: Could you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/AMJFG/ :)

Comment: The css it's kinda long to read, try to make the example a little bit shorter to minimize the problem and then update the jsfiddle so we can help you faster!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/AMJFG/1/ :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script works for me.

however if you want to try another method try the below, based on yours but a little simplified:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    headerFade();
});
function headerFade() {
    var $menu = $("header"),
        opacity = $menu.css("opacity"),
        scrollStopped,
        methods = {
            init: function(){               
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    (!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) ? $menu.fadeOut(200, methods.fadeInCallback()) : methods.fadeInCallback();                 
                });             
            },
            fadeInCallback: function(){             
                clearInterval(scrollStopped);                               
                scrollStopped = setTimeout(function () {
                    $menu.fadeIn(600);
                }, 1400);
            }
        };  
    methods.init();
};
```

Comment: hmm, this only seems to work when you get to the 'bottom' of the page :S

Comment: it works for me. ive used the mark up and css from your js fiddle.